# I am trying to call Web api Post method (i.e.PostMedication)written by me from ajax call ,It gives me error "The resource cannot be found."

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call Web api method written by me from ajax call through Postman
by URL:"http://localhost:56881/api/Medication"

```
  // POST: api/Medication
    [ResponseType(typeof(MedicationViewModel))]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostMedication(MedicationViewModel medicationViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var item = Helper.GetResponseMessage(ApplicationConstats.ErrorStatus, ApplicationConstats.ErrorStatus, null);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, item);
        }
        Medication medication = modelviewToModel(medicationViewModel);
        db.Medications.Add(medication);
        db.SaveChanges();

        var response = Helper.GetResponseMessage(ApplicationConstats.Successtatus, ApplicationConstats.Successtatus, null);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
    }
```

my call

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:56881/api/Medication',
    data: {'MedicationId':44,MedicationName:'dfgsdfgsdfg',DosageFrequency:56,DosageQuantity:464,StartDate:'09/06/2015',EndDate:'09/06/2015',IsActive:1,RefilRemaining:45,TotalQuantity:12,VisitId:4},
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){ console.log(data) }
});
```

it gives me error resource not found,please help me

Comment: How does your call look like? Are you passing the model?

Comment: Add this to your question please. It's nearly unreadable.

Comment: The action result is expecting to see a single json object that it can match up to the model.  You are sending the fields individually.

Comment: I am also calling it in Postman tool but it gives me same error over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Dean.DePue already said, you're passing the parameters individually. The ajax calls a method which looks like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Medication(int MedicationId, String MedicationName, int DosageFrequenzy ... etc etc){}
```

You have to pass an object witch matches your viewmodel. I assume these parameters represent your viewmodel.

This would be an approach:

```
<script>
var data = "{ MedicationId: 44, MedicationName: xy, DosageFrequenzy: 123 etc.}";

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:56881/api/Medication',
    data: data,
    success: function(data){ console.log(data) }
});

</script>
```